# SQL Server - Drop constraint and add default value at once

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to alter 'ID' column of my table 'MyTable' in order to remove a constraint but also to add a default value so I do:

To drop constraint I do:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT [ID]
```

To add default value to column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR ID
```

Is it possible to do it at once in one SQL statement?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. You probably can drop 2 constraints, or add 2 constraint, but it does not seem possible to drop 1 and add 1 (to the extent of my knowledge and testing). If you find out how, post to the answer below.

Comment: ADD and DROP are mutually exclusive alternatives in [the grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx) You can't do both.

Comment: They require an exclusive lock on the table , and since they are seperate transactional statements, SQL Server cannot execute them together. After all, how do you insert a constraint where it already exists? So the trandaction must occur after the previous command is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer this question by referring to [the grammar in books online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx).

```
ALTER TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   
{   
      ALTER COLUMN column_name ...
    | ADD   ...
    | DROP   ...
    | [ WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK } ] { CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT   ...
    | { ENABLE | DISABLE } TRIGGER   ...
    | { ENABLE | DISABLE } CHANGE_TRACKING   ...
    | SWITCH [ PARTITION source_partition_number_expression ] ...
    | SET   ...
    | REBUILD  ... 
    | <table_option>  
    | <filetable_option>  
    | <stretch_configuration>  
}  
[ ; ]
```

The pipe character (`|`) denotes alternatives.

You must choose between `ADD` or `DROP`. You can't do both in a single `ALTER TABLE` invocation.